# How to achieve this url routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

Let me explain briefly what I need:

I have these controllers:

- User
- Product
- Comment

And these actions:

- User/Show
- Product/Show
- Comment/Show

Now the urls are like the following:

- User/Show/1
- Product/Show/3
- Comment/Show/7

I want to write a url routing to achieve this:

- User/Show/hamid-reza
- Product/Show/cars
- Comment/Show/7

How to do this?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618037/asp-net-mvc-routing-by-string-id

Comment: But if I register 3 routings for User and Product and Comments,just the first routing would work.For example if I write the routing for User above of all,all of the three part routings(like Comment/show/7 and product/show/cars and etc) would be sent to user/show/name,and as there is no user with the name cars or 7 it shows an error.I want to know how to make a difference between them?

Comment: The second part of your route shows which controller to use. In the answer I gave you you can see that route is hard-coded to the specific controller (ex Product). In your case each url will correspond to separate controller. Also I believe that simple changing of `id` parameter in actions to type `string` will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Detail",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "User", 
        action = "Show", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
        name = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```

Code Behind

```
Public ActionResult Show(int id)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is modify the signatures of your Controller methods, like so:

In your UserController:

```
public ViewResult Show(string id)
```

In your ProductController:

```
public ViewResult Show(string category)
```

and in your CommentController:

```
public ViewResult Show(int id)
```

and it will work (of course you need to change the implementation too... this is assuming, for instance, that the string "hamid-reza" is an ID of some kind).